# Behaviour bindToController in child scope versus isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I was playing around with the `bindToController` option for directives. I stumbled upon a seemingly strange difference between the behaviour using a child scope compared to an isolated scope. When I use an isolated scope, an new scope is created for the directive, but changes to the bound controller attributes are forwarded to the parent scope. Yet when I use a child scope instead, my example breaks. (Using `bindToController` using child scopes should be allowed according to http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html#improvements-in-14 )

The code:

```
{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: 'FooDirCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: {
        name: '='
    },
    template: '<div><input ng-model="vm.name"></div>'
};
```

Working demo https://jsfiddle.net/tthtznn2/

The version using a child scope:

```
{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    controller: 'FooDirCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: {
        name: '='
    },
    template: '<div><input ng-model="vm.name"></div>'
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ydLd1e00/

The changes to name are forwarded to the child scope, but not to the parent scope. This in contrast to binding to an isolated scope. Why is this?

Comment: because vm.name is string and javascript pass by value? may be, make one more nested object like vm.data.name and bind data.

Comment: It's actually true that binding to an object works in the latter case (see: http://jsfiddle.net/sbvm1nd4/ ). I still don't see why this is different between the isolated and the child scope though, I would expect the isolated scope to suffer the same problem.

Comment: its javascript nature of prototypically inheritance  - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes, I personally think that angular can change that behavior to be consistant becuase all expressions are parsed through angular's AST, but may be they choose to follow javascript nature.

Comment: I understand JavaScripts prototypal inheritance. My problem is that, by defining a two way binding to a controller, I expect changes to be propagated to the parent scope (you agree that this is what the `bindToController` option is for, right?).

Comment: The thing is, the behaviour for `bindToController` in child scopes is not really well defined: the documentation only speaks about isolated scopes: "When an isolate scope is used for a component (see above), and controllerAs is used, bindToController: true will allow a component to have its properties bound to the controller, rather than to scope. When the controller is instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings are already available."

Comment: I knew that a bit strange behavior before I know bindToController, so I understand bindToController as its bind to controller function but not $scope.

Comment: It's bind to controller but the `=` makes it a two-way binding, and this makes me expect it to work much like the case using the isolated scope. . Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91502/discussion-between-jan-willem-gmelig-meyling-and-you).

Comment: you are not only one on that thing - https://medium.com/@mnemon1ck/why-you-should-not-use-angularjs-1df5ddf6fc99#c14d - check Scope inheritance

Comment: I know about scopes. I also know about the discussion about scopes and angular. Neither of them is really of my interest now. What I am asking is: as BOTH a child scope AND an isolated scope create a NEW scope. (And yes, the first one is created through prototypal inheritance, I totally agree on that). But why is the first option doubly bounded to the newly created scope, and the second option doubly bounded to the old/parent scope? To me that just seems inconsistent.

Comment: i agree that inconsistancy. but technical approach they chose on object parsing AST is can't fixable I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using the same alias for both controllers (and has nothing to do with object vs string value as mentioned in the comments).

As you might know, the `controller as alias` syntax is merely creating an `alias` property on scope and sets it to the controller instance. Since you are using `vm` as the alias in both cases (`MainCtrl` and `FooDirCtrl`) you are "shadowing" the `MainCtrl` alias in the case of the *normal* child scope.
(In this context, "normal" means "prototypally inheriting from parent scope".)
Thus, when you are trying to evaluate `vm.name` (`vm` for `MainCtrl`) on the new scope to get the "parent value", it is actually evaluating `FooDirCtrl.name` (which is undefined) and the same happens when you are trying to assign back to the parent scope.

The *isolate* scope version is not affected, since the scope is not inheriting from it's parent scope.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/t1q12ngn/)

---

**UPDATE:**
Taking a closer look at the source code, this might be a bug (because support for `bindToController` on non-isolate scopes was added "retroactively").
We seem to have been getting away with this bug, because of the prototypal inheritance, but when the names collide we are out of luck.

I have to take a closer look to make sure if it's indeed a bug and if it's "fixable", but for now you can work around it by using different aliases for your controllers (see fiddle above).

---

That's (part of) why I don't like using `vm` as my conroller alias (despite it being suggested by popular style-guides) :)

Let's track this in [angular.js#13021](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13021).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll keep an eye on the thread. I will accept the answer when we are a bit further with this issue. I am by the way not a fan of the `vm` name either, tbh, I stole the fiddle and only adjusted it for the second example ;-)

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling: BTW, I have submitted a fix: [angular.js#13025](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/13025)

Comment: And it's merged. So, this will work correctly since `v1.5.0-beta.2`.

Comment: Its also merged in 1.4.8 which was released 4 days ago.

Comment: Looks like this bug has been reintroduced. I'm using 1.5.8 and noticed the same issue

Comment: @DaneEdw: Hardly possible (since we have tests to guard against regressions), but if it is a new bug please open an issue on GitHub (preferrably providing a live reproduction).

Comment: @ExpertSystem Nevermind. I mistakenly assumed using bindToController made the directive have isolate scope. Using the same name on the child had the effect that the attributes of the child directive show up as undefined as a result. It sure was confusing though. I guess I assumed that it was isolate scope because when you bind attributes to the scope you're using isolate scope.